# Why are Gazebo textures and colors mixed up with background windows or black?

Tags: gazebo-11

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Hi,

I'm running Gazebo 11.5.1 and ROS Galactic on Ubuntu 20.
When I load the house model in gazebo, I get the following.

[image: image description]

The textures and colors are not right and mixed with the visual of the other software windows that I'm running.
Any ideas on what could be causing the issue?

More details:

- When I start an empty gazebo world  and add objects to it, they are loaded just fine.
- If I save the model  and load it, the objects have weird appearance again.
- If I add a new instance of an object,  it appears the exact same as the one in the model with weird texture and    color.

Tested it it with a fresh Gazebo build from source too but the problem is still there. This is really blocking because I'm testing a visual slam algorithm so the scene appearance is critical.

Any help would be appreciated!

Thanks,

Jas

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/27397/why-are-gazebo-textures-and-colors-mixed-up-with-background-windows-or-black?/) by [JasBot](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/56341/jasbot/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 1 on 2021-09-27

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

So, This problem was here for a while but it was fixed "on it's own".

I had some problems with my graphics card driver so I reinstalled everything and checked the BIOS settings as well.
Once everything reinstalled, the texture and color rendering was working fine again.

It was a confusing problem to have and no errors or warnings were detected even in verbose mode.

---

Originally posted by [JasBot](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/56341/jasbot/) with karma: 1 on 2021-10-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0